# How to run a live stream as local radio

Tags: ubuntu, streaming

Users.

I want to play a live stream **http://204.45.41.148/** with icecast2 server.I have successfully installed icecast2 and ices2.I want my users to connect to my server for listening this channel instead of playing it from original originator radio.

Like mapping to my local host instead of  connection to remote end.So far I could not find any thing to make this work.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.